# How to get $ style end of file Using Powershell Out-File

Tags: powershell

I'm having issues with line endings.  I have a file tracked by git.  Then I'm trying to recreate that file with PowerShell with `$content | Out-File $location` and git is tracking a change in the line ending at EOF.

If in the terminal I run `file ./somefile.sql` (the file already in git)
I get an output `./somefile.sql ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Running `cat -ve ./somefile.sql`
The last 2 lines of the file shows

```sh
^M$
END^M$   #'END' is actual text in the file
```

If in the terminal I run `file ./dupfile.sql` (the file created by PowerShell)
I get an output `./dupfile.sql ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`

Running `cat -ve ./dupfile.sql`
The last 2 lines of the file shows

```sh
^M$
END$
```

If I change Out-File to use `$content | Out-File $location -NoNewLine` and check the `dupfile` outputs again I get:
`ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`
...but...

```sh
^M$
END%
```

How can I use `Out-File` to write `$content` and get a `^M$` ending like the one I have in git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following (assuming that `$content` contains a string):

```
Set-Content -NoNewLine $location -Value ($content + "`r`n")
```

The solution above assumes that `$content` is a single, multiline string and appends a CRLF sequence to it (represented as `` "`r`n" ``, an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) with escape sequences), then writes it as-is to the target file, using `-NoNewLine`.
Read on for background information.

---

If you know you're dealing with *strings*, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) performs better than [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file).

Both cmdlets exhibit the same newline handling (though their default *character encoding* differs in *Windows PowerShell*, fortunately no longer in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where (BOM-less) UTF-8 is consistently used):

- With *multiple* input objects, the *platform-native* newline sequence is inserted between the (stringified) objects on saving, i.e. CRLF on Windows, LF on Unix - as reflected in `[Environment]::NewLine`.
- By default, a *trailing* platform-native newline is appended.

Regarding `-NoNewLine`:

- `-NoNewLine` doesn't just suppress a *trailing* newline, but also newlines *between* multiple input objects, if applicable.
- If the input is a *single, multiline string*, you can use `-NoNewLine` to write it to a file as-is to a file (which means that that string's trailing-newline-or-not status is preserved as is). With *multiple* strings, however, you effectively get *string concatenation without a separator*.

Note that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) has a `-Delimiter` parameter, which `Out-File` and `Set-Content` / `Add-Content` lack.

[GitHub issue #3855](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3855) proposes introducing this parameter, which would allow you request use of a non-native newline sequence on demand, such as `` -Delimiter "`r`n" `` on Unix, and `` -Delimiter "`n" `` on Windows.